# Anonymous voting on google forms

Tags: google-forms

I have this situation:

A group of people must vote using Google Forms. Their voting choices must be anonymous. But, they don't have gmail accounts and we would like to collect who has voted and who hasn't.

As I can see, if I add a question where they fill their name, that makes their personal choice connected to their name in the data.

But is there a way to make that "name question" separate. Maybe making two forms with separate data collection but connecting them in one form (with maybe two pages) so it is more convenient to users?

EDIT: MORE GENERAL:

How to separate data collected from one question so it isn't linked to other question? Can two forms be merged together for answering but separated in data view?

Comment: The fact that they can fill in a fake name is irrelevant to the question, I assume? Otherwise all bets are off..

Comment: @JanDoggen: It is irrelevant. Question is only how to make google form where data from one question is saved separately from others and can't be linked

Comment: To the reader: anonymizing data is important to preserve privacy, but sensitive data may still be needed, for example to contact the winner of a prize for participating.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you can't really separate/unlink the Google Form question unless you are creating 2 separate forms. Currently there's no way to track the person who votes without tracking their choice. This can only be done via Google App Script.
What you can do is generate a passcode and email to voters, then the passcode section is created to allow voters to input the correct passcode before proceed. Make sure the passcode and passcode email is sent automatically and deleted permanently from the senders email to maintain anonymous purpose. After that you could probably save the email and passcode in a variable and make a tick whenever the passcode is received. I'm not IT security experts so I'm not sure whether saving the email and passcode in a variable/script properties will violate the anonymous voting or not.

Feel free to look at add-on developed for this: https://blog.cre8tivenow.com/google-form-voting/
This add-on helps the generation of passcode, send passcode to voters, setup passcode section in Google Form and deleting the sent email automatically. However it won't be able to track who votes.

PS: I'm one of the developer.

Comment: From [How to not be a spammer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) "Don't include links except to support what you've written. Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer itself, and links should always be directly relevant to a part of your answer. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer"